# Why have <?php and ?> on every line

Tags: php, theme-development, customization

I've seen this convention pretty much everywhere, and, at times, it comes close to driving me nuts:

```
<?php //The loop ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Where the `<?php` and closing `?>` are on every single line, even if there is no intervening HTML code.

**My question is: Why?**  Why include all these extra tags?

To me, it seems this convention adds a significant amount of clutter to code, is annoying to follow in the first place, and adds that many more places to accidentally leave out an opening or closing tag.

**NOTE**

This is code pulled from the Twenty-Twelve theme, the example given by WordPress.

Comment: also, shorthand while statements =o

Comment: Flagging to close - there is no definitive answer to this question, and it's certainly not a WP specific issue - any person working with PHP will face this issue

Comment: @anu: First, a question may not always have a single, definitive answer (though it still may have a best answer).  The guidelines say "practical, and answerable".  Second, yes, this is technically a PHP issue, but I've seen this much, much more in my short time working with WP. So, while this isn't limited to WP, it seems to me to be correlated enough to ask in a WP setting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not recommended in any WordPress style guide, and I think it is a bad coding style. Beginners are using this style, maybe because it feels more like HTML …

Unfortunately, the default themes are using this style way too often, so some beginners might think it is part of a code style.

One disadvantage of this style is comment handling. Look closely at the following example and how it doesn't do what the author might expect:

```
<?php echo 'Important: '; // announcement ?>
<?php echo ' enter the word '; /* start ?>
<?php echo '<b>password</b>'; /* the end */ ?>
```

Good luck debugging that. :)

Rule: Switch between PHP and HTML context only if you have to create output in of both languages. Use regular line breaks in all other cases.

**Update, further thoughts:** Every valid HTML file is a complete and valid PHP program. Yes, even if it does not contain a single line of actual PHP code.

If you start from HTML and add small pieces of PHP step by step … you might end up with the style we’re discussing here. That’s where **refactoring** comes into the game: Once everything runs as expected, rewrite the code until it is as readable as possible, easy to maintain and to extend, without repeating parts.

I guess some people are happy without this last step, and that’s why this won’t die soon.

Comment: It's a pity that the syntax highlighting above doesn't show what actually happens with that comment...

Comment: @webaware I think that illustrates the problem even more. :)

Comment: True :)   (plus some chars to keep SE comment police happy)

Comment: Saying "This is not recommended anywhere" goes too far. I recommend this, and though I am very possibly in the minority, I've developed enough themes to hold a semi-valid opinion :).

Comment: @AndyAdams Fair enough, I have rephrased that. And now go away, you evil recommender. :)

Comment: Themes use this style because doing otherwise is just too ugly. When refactoring themes, I'd prefer to rewrite the code to be as readable as possible, and that means not having echo/printf/var_dump all around and to put each control structures inside their own pairs of `<? ... ?>` to make nesting easier to comprehend. One thing I'd do differently than the OP's example though, is that I'd put `the_post();` on its own line.

Comment: It seems to me that there's perhaps some processing overhead considerations. If you run everything or nearly everything in a single `<?php ... ?>`, you may inadvertently use slow processes to make the final output, while everything between `?>` and `<?php` resolves naturally and takes virtually no server overhead that it wouldn't already need for plain html.

Comment: I'm seeing this everywhere in multiple CMS, I'm pretty sure this isn't the reason.

Comment: Could it be security somehow?  Everything inside PHP is parsed, by closing all the time you avoid accidentally parsing something

Answer (score 13):

While I avoid this for PHP comments, I am an avid PHP opener/closer in template files. The alternative involves echoing HTML via PHP strings, which looks even worse in my opinion. As a primitive example:

```
<!-- Example 1 -->
<ul>
    <?php
        foreach ( $list_items as $list_item ) {
            echo "<li><a href='" . $list_item->url . "'>" . $list_item->name . "</a></li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>

<!-- Example 2 -->
<ul>
    <?php foreach ( $list_items as $list_item ) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $list_item->url; ?>">
                <?php echo $list_item->name; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Is example 2 more verbose? Perhaps? But easier to read and edit, in my opinion. You can imagine how ugly it can get for complex HTML.

Also, just as a side note: using `endforeach` and `endif` when writing HTML between your PHP logic enhances readability a *ton* compared to `}`.

Comment: the huge advantage of `}`over `endif` however is that (in many editors) you can easily see where the opening `{` is and therefore whether everything has been properly closed. Try figuring that out with `endif` and a whole bunch of conditionals...

Comment: `foreach ( $list_items as $list_item ) printf( '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>', $list_item->url, $list_item->name );` – **two** lines, HTML and PHP nicely separated. :P

Comment: @toscho: You totally missed the point. You're still mixing PHP and HTML, people that prefers the second style does it because we want to avoid having HTML inside PHP string. I use the second style when using PHP as a templating language because it is the only way to nest a mixture of PHP and HTML sensibly, while I use the former when using PHP as a scripting language because there is usually no good reason to have HTML in the script when you separate the application logic from the template. The second style would be even better if short tags are available: `<? ... ?>` and `<?= ... ?>`.

Comment: @Piet: if you have troubles matching up braces, you probably never heard of indentation? Also, you should be able to configure to highlight the opening of `endif` in any decent editors.

Comment: @LieRyan thanks for assuming. I will refrain from further commenting.

Comment: @LieRyan [Be nice.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette)

Comment: It could be related to this https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ I agree with the answer here it looks much nicer.  And although harder to find the opening/closing if statements without parenthesis, the advantage is that you can troubleshoot all of the other elements more easiliy and don't have so many nested functions.

Comment: The Joomla documentation gives this reason.  "This should make the code easier to read and make it easier to move blocks around without creating fatal errors due to missing <?php ... ?> tags." and suggests it's mainly used in mixed language situations like the answer here shows.

Answer (score 10):

This is about choice between seeing page as:

- as completely PHP-generated entity
- as HTML document template, powered by PHP template tags

Different people tend to think about it differently. Note that functions rarely use this style, because they feel more like block of pure PHP. On other hand it's not uncommon in templates because they are more spread across files and amount of pure HTML can be easily more than that of PHP in them.

If you look at templating engines (Mustache, Twig, etc) - they look very much like this style except that their syntax tends to eliminate verbosity of plain PHP.

PS I want to note that I am talking about *sane* embedding of PHP in HTML, not *literally* opening and ending tags on *every* line just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: Why? Why include all these extra tags?

The answer is pretty simple: Audience. When people (not programmers) grab a theme, then FTPing up their install, running the 5min setup and so on already feels like programming to them. When they then want to add or change a single line of *whatever* in their theme, then they maybe already figured out what HTML is. PHP still will be far out of their reach. So my guess is that the idea behind this is to allow easier adding or removing of elements without breaking everthing when they make a mistake.

Note: This is not what I like, prefer or would recommend. It's just what I think why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some new programmers are trained this way.  I'm following a 40 hour course on Lynda and the instructor is dropping PHP tags on every line, with the exception of function definitions.  It's probably to clearly draw lines between HTML and PHP, which  probably helps new people understand where HTML ends and PHP begins.  After that, its probably a habit.  I was starting to get annoyed by it myself and decided to see if anyone else was complaining.