# Wordpress get_avatar function not correct working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php, functions

My code doing this, listing which author have posted in the current category. But get_avatar function not correct working. Im Using Simple Local Avatar Plugin. It is working author.php don't have any problem. But when i use it my this code, it is listing same and wrong author picture(My latest author picture. [You can look this picture](http://www.screencast.com/t/O02Y5bOx4y0))

My Code:

```
<?php if (is_category()) {
$current_category = single_cat_title(“”, false);
$author_array = array();
$args = array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'category_name' => $current_category,
'orderby' => 'author',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$cat_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) :
if (!in_array($cat_post->post_author,$author_array)) {
$author_array[] = $cat_post->post_author;
}
endforeach;
foreach ($author_array as $author) :
$auth = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
$autid= get_userdata($author)->ID;
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '32' );
echo "<a href='?author=";
echo $autid;
echo "'>";
echo $auth;
echo "</a>";
echo "<br />";
endforeach;
}?>
```

Comment: *Off-topic:* you don't need a closing PHP tag `?>`, if you are going to open it in the very next line `<?php` without any Html in between (check this [Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/79938/12615)). Also, indent the code so it is easier to read (for you and for the ones that may be willing to help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pull the author ID here:

```
$autid= get_userdata($author)->ID;
```

So why aren't you using it to get the avatar on the very next line?

```
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '32' );
```

[`get_avatar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) will accept the ID as a parameter. Try this instead:

```
echo get_avatar( $autid, '32' );
```

[`get_the-author_email`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/deprecated.php#L1471) is deprecated anyway so even if it worked you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Yes this is true im used this `echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '32' );` so many wrong and im a little confused..It is working perfectly now.Thank you for answer.

Comment: That code should work (until the deprecated function is removed) under the right circumstances, but you already have the ID so the function call would be pointless anyway.