# If else statement to check for thumbnail and whether or not it's a mobile device - streamline

Tags: php

This code works but since my php skills are not so good, I'm trying to learn how I can make this cleaner.

This uses php_mobile_detect plugin which I've updated with new classes since the plugin author hasn't updated in awhile. It checks for the device, if it's not a phone loads one size image and then if it is loads another size and then it also checks that the post has an image so I don't have empty stuff in my html.

**QUESTION: How to make this more streamlined?**

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { /* CHECK FOR THUMBNAIL */ ?>
<?php global $post; ?>
<?php if ( wpmd_is_notphone() ){ /* IF NOT PHONE */ ?>
<?php /* IF NOT PHONE */ $srcdt = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 800,300 ), true, '' ); ?>

<div class="entry-content" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $srcdt[0]; ?> )" >
<?php } else { /* GET SMALLER IMAGE */ ?>
<?php $srcph = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 500,200 ), true, '' ); ?>
<div class="entry-content" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $srcph[0]; ?> )" >
<?php } /* END GET BACKGROUND THUMBNAIL */ ?>
<?php } else { /* IF NO THUMBNAIL */ ?>
<div class="entry-content">
   <?php } /* END IF ELSE THUMBNAIL */ ?>
   <div class="article-body clearfix">
      <?php the_content( __("Continue...","chrissy") ); ?>
   </div>
   <!-- /.article-body -->

</div>
<!-- /.entry-content -->
```

Comment: [Why have <?php and ?> on every line](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/79938/why-have-php-and-on-every-line)

Comment: I'm afraid to get rid of it. I should have started with learning php and then Wordpress but I didn't. I just needed a blog for myself and I looked for a theme that I liked and can't find one so I am making it myself.

Comment: @toscho: I'm going to try echoing this stuff so it looks better. I'm the only one going to use this anyway. I read that post, thanks!

Comment: You only need to open and close php tags when you move from php to html or html to php. If this is done correctly, you don't need to abuse echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it is hard to read and you don’t see clearly what the real goal is. Always start with the desired minimal result, then make it more flexible, but keep the logic for that separate.

All you need is a `<div class="entry-content">`, maybe with a `style` attribute. So start with that:

```
<div class="entry-content" <?php echo $style; ?>>
```

Now you need a variable `$style` that might hold some content. Set it to an empty string per default:

```
$style = '';
```

And now you need the logic to fill that variable. Again, [don’t repeat yourself](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself). The only change in your calls to `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` is the size argument, so separate that out. Also make sure [your URL doesn’t contain dangerous code, use `esc_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#URLs).

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $size  = wpmd_is_notphone() ? array ( 800, 300 ) : array ( 500, 200 );
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), $size, TRUE, '' );

    if ( $thumb )
        $url = esc_url( $thumb[ 0 ] );

    if ( '' !== $url )
        $style = " style='background-image:$url'";
}
```

Now you can even go further and move that logic into a function, and that function to your theme’s `functions.php`. That will keep the template clean, and you can reuse the function in other places.

Such a function could look like this:

```
/**
 * Get a style attribute with a background image URL
 *
 * @param  array $default  The default size
 * @param  array $phone    The size for phones
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_172203_get_thumb_attribute( $default =  array ( 800, 300 ), $phone = array ( 500, 200 ) ) {

    if ( ! has_post_thumbnail() )
        return '';

    $size     = wpmd_is_notphone() ? $default : $phone;
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $thumb    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, $size, TRUE, '' );

    if ( ! $thumb )
        return '';

    $url = esc_url( $thumb[ 0 ] );

    if ( '' === $url )
        return '';

    return " style='background-image:url($url)'";
}
```

In your template you just need this now:

```
<div class="entry-content" <?php echo wpse_172203_get_thumb_attribute(); ?>>
    <div class="article-body clearfix">
        <?php the_content( __( "Continue...", "chrissy" ) ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can reuse the function in other places with different parameters, for example in a loop:

```
<div class="excerpt" <?php
    echo wpse_172203_get_thumb_attribute(
        array ( 500, 250 ),
        array ( 250, 125 )
    ); ?>>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
```

And do not forget to send a HTTP `Vary` header:

```
header( 'Vary: User-Agent' );
```

Otherwise, the output will be cached in proxy servers, and your content will be sent to the wrong recipient. Generally, you shouldn’t try to detect the user agent per PHP. The `Vary` header will [break caching for all browsers](http://zoompf.com/blog/2010/03/the-big-performance-improvement-in-ie9-no-one-is-talking-about), so in the end, your site is much slower now than without the “optimized” images. Use client-side code like CSS or JavaScript for that. User agent strings from browsers are not reliable anyway. PHP is the wrong tool for that task.

Comment: Holy crap this is awesome. I need to pay you some dough, I feel guilty. I read up on the php_mobile_detect: Mobile Detect is a lightweight PHP class for detecting mobile devices (including tablets). It uses the User-Agent string combined with specific HTTP headers to detect the mobile environment... I've used it for a couple years -- after I hired someone to make it work with smarty with CMSMS -- and I've noticed it speeds up on phones.

Comment: It works smoothly and I learned a lot. I don't want to edit your post but this `return " style='background-image:url($url)'";` was missing the css.

Comment: @Christina Thanks, I have changed it. Feel free to edit any post on our site, mine included.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a ternary like this:

```
$output = has_post_thumbnail() && wpmd_is_notphone() ? $has_image : $no_image;
```